# Architecture for syncing data with remote server

Tags: php, mysql, architecture, synchronization

Current scenario : 
There is a webservice (build in php/mysql). User filled data is stored on a remote server.

Issue is user has extremely bad internet connection, webservice is down most of the time. Is there a way to store data locally and sync it when internet is available?
Please note, user might not have database installed on his machine also there is no localserver to work with.

Comment: You need to store the information somewhere locally, so database is required, otherwise tell him to get a new internet connection.

Comment: good suggestion ;-)...but that might not be always a solution...what if the user is travelling and the connectivity is on/off frequently. Also sometimes users want to push data only when on WIFI or unmetered connections instead of Mobile Data...

Answer (score 1):

Even if user had some type of RDBMS installed on the box, you probably wouldn't have any way to communicate with it. You can use the HTML 5 [Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), but it will not solve the connection issues.

And since `localStorage` (which you probably would use) is available directly only from JavaScript, you would have to make a complicated and fully functional JS application to utilize it.

> <sub>**Note:** based on your profile, I would estimate that your JavaScript skills would **not** be adequate for such task.</sub>

If your target audience is mobile users, then you have another alternative: create a native application.

You would still be able to use HTML for the interface (using built in web browser components). But it also would let you have SQLite DB and file storage available on the mobile device, where you can cache the necessary data.

Comment: I doubt if localStorage would suffice, as there will be need to upload images. 
My target audience are not mobile user.
Also, if user has some sort of RDBMS installed, the data can be uploaded when the internet is available.

Comment: Even if user has some type of RDBMS installed (sqlite, mysql, etc.), you would have **no way** to access it from JS. And you cannot run backend's code on user's machine

Comment: I cannot, but the user can. When the net is up, he can say, click a button to upload data, the issue is, how to maintain relational view without having a RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

look at the features in HTML 5 for local storage
Typically I would go with IndexDB and then push the local data to the server once the connection is back

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html - Should give you a brief about the features and implementation.